# How to have an arbitrary precision and integrate with scipy in python?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to integrate this:

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import tplquad

def f(y,x,z):
    return  2*np.sin(z)*np.cos(np.arctan((2*np.cos(y)-0.5+x)/(2*np.sin(y))))

tplquad(f,0,np.pi/2, lambda z: 0, lambda z:1, lambda z, x: 0, lambda z, x: np.pi/2,)
```

But I tried a lot of method, nothing works and I'm not sure to have the best method. What is the best lib to integrate with an arbitrary precision and use it in the scipy tplwuad ? I need to adjust the precision in the same time in the tplquad function or not ?

Answer (score 1):

from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 30

def f1(y,x,z):
    return  2*mp.sin(z)*mp.cos(mp.atan((2*mp.sin(y)-0.5+x)/(2*mp.cos(y))))

def f2(y,x,z):
    return  2*mp.cos(z)*mp.sin(mp.atan((2*mp.sin(y)-0.5+x)/(2*mp.cos(y))))

print mp.quad(f1,[0,mp.pi/2], [0,1],[0,mp.pi/2])
print mp.quad(f2,[0,mp.pi/2], [0,1],[0,mp.pi/2])